# Duplicating every frame in ffmpeg

Tags: duplicates, frames

I'm planning on filming a stop-motion at 12 fps, and need to duplicate every frame once. I would rather not do it in camera (save my mirror) - is it possble to do this in ffmpeg? (I've seen lots of posts on removing duplicates, but not on inserting them)

Thanks
Gillian